# Codigniter and Wordpress Bridge for image Upload

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am uploading an image in `Codeigniter` and I need to upload the same image in `Wordpress`. So I tried following thing:

1. After uploading I called a file which start from following code, but the variable `site_url` created issue because both CI and WP are using this so got "variable redeclare issue".

   ```
   define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
   require_once( 'wp-config.php' );
   ```
2. I did another implementation, after uploading image I stored `$_FILES` in session  and tried send image information using session which is not working.

Any one can suggest how I can complete this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step you need to include 
**wp-load.php** from wordpress

Once you include that file you can use any wordpress function in your ci.

After this you can use this one

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95125/custom-image-upload

Comment: Could you explain path of "include.php" and what code should be available in this file.

Comment: Sorry file name you need to include is wp-load.php

Its available in root dictionary of wordpress